# Using OpenSSL v1.0.1g, am I creating SSL certificate or TLS certificate?

Tags: tls

So confuse right now between SSLv3 and TLSv1.2, I tried to find some answer on the Web but didn't seems figure it out so I am asking you guys.

Is using the latest release of OpenSSL make me creating TLS certificate ? If yes, how can I verify this ? Is it possible to look into the certificate to find in wich version it was signed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSL and TLS are the same thing.

To be precise, SSL is the "old name": it means *Secure Sockets Layer*. It was the name of the protocol originally defined by Netscape. The last version of that protocol (SSL 3.0) has been later on published as [RFC 6101](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101).

In early 1999, the protocol was turned into an IETF standard, not something owned by a private corporation. This implied a change of name, both to symbolically assert the will to push the protocol into the public, implementable by anybody, and also to avoid intellectual property issues. The new name is *Transport Layer Security*, aka "TLS". This also expresses the idea that TLS can be applied to various transport channels, not just *sockets*.

So TLS 1.0 was published as [RFC 2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246). The authors took the opportunity to iron out a few historical quirks, meaning that TLS 1.0 is *very similar*, but not completely bit-to-bit equal, to SSL 3.0. Down on the wire, TLS 1.0 clients and servers actually announce the protocol version as "SSL 3.1".

As for the *certificates*, there is no difference. "SSL certificate" is the colloquial term for "a certificate that is fit for a SSL server". Such a certificate would work equally well for a TLS server, and vice versa. Certificates exist outside of SSL/TLS, and there is no notion of SSL/TLS protocol version which would apply to certificates. There is no place within a certificate where it would be written "this certificate is for SSL 3.0" or "this certificate is for TLS 1.0".

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is called OpenSSL and not OpenTLS because it is a derivative of an older library called SSLeay, which was written years before the name change to TLS. *A contrario*, the [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) library, a competitor to OpenSSL, was started *after* the name switch, and is sponsored by people who value naming correction over pedagogy (let's face it, the "SSL" acronym remains much more widely known and understood than "TLS").

Comment: Thanks, now I will separate x509 certs from the SSL/TLS protocol. I was in the idea of both are the same this as because using them all day long, sometimes you get confused. Also, I was able to find another answer of this question by using "Openssl s_connect" to specify the protocol to use (ex: openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -tls1_2") and the returning values is telling me if TLS in valid or not. Thanks again !!